# several questions regarding cytoscape.js

Tags: javascript, graph, cytoscape.js

I've just started using [cytoscape](https://js.cytoscape.org/) (with [cytoscape-klay layout](https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js-klay)) to render some graphs and I'm unable to find answers to some of the questions I have:

1. Is there a way to left-align the graph? (graph seems to be centered horizontally, but in my use case, I need it to start from the left)
   **Edit: my graph is not pannable nor zoomable and `panBy` and `shift` doesn't seem to work**
2. Is there a way to get the graph rendered without specifying the container dimensions? (right now, if I don't specify the dimensions, the canvas itself has a dimension of 0x0 and since I specify a width/height for every node, I think it should be possible)
   **Edit: I can't use an absolute positioned container since my view has some sticky parts. Also, I want the container dimension to be exactly what the graph needs as it is not pannable. I'm currently doing the following to accommodate both 1 and 2:**

```
const dim = cy.$('*').boundingBox(); // get real size of graph
const container = document.getElementById('#cy');
container.setAttribute('style', `width: ${dim.w - 120}px; height: ${dim.h}px; transform: translateX(-175px)`);
```

3. Is there a way to define css in a css file or does it have to be in js?
   **Edit: I'm aware that I can use a js/json file - I'm wondering if I can also use a css file (I assume not, but I just want to make sure)**
4. my nodes should be interactive (open / close) and since I work with Vue.js I prefer having my nodes as Vue components. while this seems impossible with cytoscape itself as it supports only a label for a node, I found [nodeHtmlLabel](https://github.com/kaluginserg/cytoscape-node-html-label) package that gets me really close, it doesn't adhere to the styles that were set in js and reactivity seems to be a problem. Is there a better alternative?
   **Edit: I'm not asking about compound nodes. For a simple example of what I need, you can think of each node having a title and a description but only the title is visible and if you click on the node, it will open to show the description (node height would change)**
5. can I customize the edges? (have an edge consist of a straight line connected to a bezier curved line, use my own control points, etc.) If not, how does these weights / distances work? do they work equally well for Top-Down and Left-Right graphs? (I'm trying to have something like [this](https://cubic-bezier.com/#1,0,0,1))
   **Edit: I'm aware of the current edge types, but I'm looking for something that is a merge between `taxi` and `bezier`. Since this is not currently supported, I wanted to know if there is any way to define a custom line myself**

Background - I managed to get really close to the desired design with [dagre-d3](https://github.com/dagrejs/dagre-d3) but I have a problem with ranks and it seems that this package is unmaintained :(, hence I decided to look for an alternative

Comment: Please remember that this is **not** a general help forum: refamiliarise yourself with SO by taking the [tour] and rereading [what is on-topic](/help/on-topic) here. All these questions fall under the ["search and research before asking"](/help/how-to-ask) policy: SO is your last resort after you can't find the information in the obvious places (google, cyctoscape forum, other questions already asked on SO, etc.). It's not a convenient website to offload the effort of looking these things up yourself.

Comment: Thanks @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans but I did some research before I posted these questions and couldn't find answers as I stated above